# Javascript is not loading on server, it is working well at localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I used it in application.js

```
 //= require_tree .
```

working well at localhost, but .js file isn't loading at server as a website. Can any1 tell whats the problem?

Comment: And what the heck is this? BTW check file path. i think file path is not correct and hens you js file is not loading.

Comment: Have you look in the browser console for errors, that would be a good place to start....

Comment: @NewTOJs there is no error came up in console at localhost.

Comment: Are you using hardcoded paths? If it's launched on a server then your website will be expecting `public/js/../*.js` etc rather than `C:/jsfiles/*.js`

Comment: @alive to die if file path is wrong it wont run locally.

Comment: @Aastik  i am taking on server no localhost. file urls become different  in local/server

Comment: @jay gould , i am using mvvc for paths

Comment: Add in your *actual* code as to how you're including JS files in your OP. Right now it's impossible to understand what *might* be going wrong.

Comment: @alive to die, i m getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: okay @jay gould

Comment: @Aastik `replace` is a string operator so that's for a different question entirely.

Comment: yeah... i'll provide u the code in some time

Comment: i think this occurs due to the production and development environment mode . I think i commit code at development mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use "rake assets:precompile" before commit your code in development mode which make the js file to load at server.
Be careful of environment development and production. While committing use
production and while coding use development mode.